An inequality my teacher gave me last month
Given $a,b,c > 0$ satisfying $a+b+c=3$.
Find the minimum value of the expression
$$M = 6\left[\dfrac{1}{a^2(b+c)} + \dfrac{1}{b^2(c+a)} + \dfrac{1}{c^2(a+b)} \right] - 5(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
My attempt (sorry for my bad English)
We have:
\begin{align*}
6\left[\dfrac{1}{a^2(b+c)} + \dfrac{1}{b^2(c+a)} + \dfrac{1}{c^2(a+b)} \right] &= \dfrac{2(a+b+c)}{a^2(b+c)} + \dfrac{2(a+b+c)}{b^2(c+a)} + \dfrac{2(a+b+c)}{c^2(a+b)} \\
& = \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2}{a^2} + \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2}{a(b+c)}
\end{align*}
Use CBS inequality we have:
$$\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2}{a(b+c)} \ge \dfrac{9}{ab+bc+ca} \ge \dfrac{9}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
$$\sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2}{a^2} \ge \dfrac{18}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$
So
$$M \ge \dfrac{27}{a^2+b^2+c^2} - 5(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
Let $t = a^2+b^2+c^2$ so $t \ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{3} = 3$
Rewrite $M = \dfrac{27}{t} - 5t$
We need to prove that $M \ge -6$
$$\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{27}{t} - 5t \ge -6$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0 < t \le 3 \hspace{0.2cm} (\text{wrong, i think so})$$
After, I use $-5(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 10(ab+bc+ca) - 45$ and let $z = ab+bc+ca \le 3$
So $M = \dfrac{18}{9 - 2z} + \dfrac{9}{z} + 10z - 45$
We need to prove that $M \ge -6$ but it isn't working
How I can prove this inequality?

Remark. Another way is: By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\dfrac{1}{a^2(b+c)} + \dfrac{1}{b^2(c+a)} + \dfrac{1}{c^2(a+b)}
\ge \frac{(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)^2}{(b+c) + (c+a) + (a+b)}.$$
It suffices to prove that
$$(1/a + 1/b + 1/c)^2 - 5(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \ge -6.$$
We can use the pqr method. However, it is not nice.

The minimum is $-6$ when $a=b=c=1$.
Proof.
WLOG, assume that $a = \max(a, b, c)$. Then $1\le a < 3$. Let $x := bc$. Then $x \le (b+c)^2/4 = (3-a)^2/4$.
By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{1}{b^2(c+a)} + \frac{1}{c^2(a+b)}
\ge \frac{(1/b + 1/c)^2}{(c + a) + (a + b)}
= \frac{(3-a)^2}{3 + a}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}.$$
Also, we have
$b^2 + c^2 = (b + c)^2 - 2bc = (3-a)^2 - 2x$.
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{6}{a^2(3-a)} + \frac{6(3-a)^2}{3 + a}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2} - 5a^2 - 5(3-a)^2 + 10x \ge -6. \tag{1}$$
Let $f(x) := \mathrm{LHS}_{(1)} - \mathrm{RHS}_{(1)}$. We have
$$f'(x) = - \frac{12(3-a)^2}{(3+a)x^3} + 10
\le - \frac{12(3-a)^2}{(3+a)}\cdot \frac{1}{((3-a)^2/4)^3} + 10$$
$$= -\frac{768}{(3-a)^3(9 - a^2)} + 10
\le -\frac{768}{(3-1)^3(9 - 1^2)} + 10 = -2 < 0. $$
Using $x \le (3-a)^2/4$, it suffices to prove that
$$f((3-a)^2/4) \ge 0,$$
or
$$\frac{3(a-1)^2}{2a^2(3-a)^2(3+a)}
(-5a^5 + 15a^4 + 39a^3 - 129a^2 + 72a + 36)\ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.
